# Why hide .NET URL extensions and make them appear to be .html?

Tags: domains, url, url-rewriting, masking

I'm new to the web engineering and I have done some searching for **URL/Domain masking**. In my company, my HOD asked one question during meeting and wants the answer in the next meeting. He asked that *why are some sites will hide their real file type*?

E.g. `http://example/examplefolder/page.NET` into `http://example/examplefolder/page.html`. Why the extension of the pages will always end up in `html`? Is is the reason to prevent some *curious* outsider from trying to attack the web site? Is this related with **URL rewritting**?

Comment: See [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48271/why-are-extensions-often-hidden-on-urls) related question. Since you're asking about why one extension would be used in-replace of another, I'm reopening this.

Comment: Cool URIs do not show an extension at all, for all the good reason explained in https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI , see "What to leave out" section.

Comment: There's no such thing as a .net file extension. It's .asp or a variant. More here on file extensions on the web. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614520/what-are-common-file-extensions-for-web-programming-languages

Comment: @abunooh the .net extension if for netViz Project Files: https://www.reviversoft.com/file-extensions/net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be several reasons for changing the file extension - though this is not necessarily to "hide" anything.

Two might be:

1. Consistency: By using index.html, the webmaster can change the platform they use and be consistent - from a .Net platform to .PHP platform to a platform outputting the more typical .html - and not worry about having to change later;
2. User Expectation: Users expect .html and it may be thought using .html will make them more comfortable.